# Relation between WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter and ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-4, spring-oauth2

I'm trying to integrate Spring OAuth2 into Spring MVC REST. Most of the Spring OAuth2 examples, there is only `ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter` and some of have `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` as well. I'm not going to integrate OAuth with Google, Facebook, etc. I'm trying to provide a token based authentication for Spring MVC REST which is currently based on `Basic` Authentication. Can someone exaplin me what is required and not or good resource to understand the Spring MVC REST +OAuth integration in a single server?

Currently my POC works without `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`, but with `ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter` along with `AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter`. It looks like `ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter` is enough. Now I'm not sure what should I do to my existing `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` which is working perfectly in my Spring MVC REST application.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Here is a good answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/28604260, it looks like WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter is an order inferior to the ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter.

I have a WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter and a ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter, but the endpoints security configuration is in the ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter under:

```
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
```

I also have the following configuration:

```
security:
    oauth2:
        resource:
            filter-order: 3
```

Else the endpoints security configuration is ignored (I don't know why).

Comment: this worked for me too. with this, I don't need a `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` at all -- `ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter` does everything. I observed the filter chain with `logging.level.org.springframework.security: DEBUG`, across 3 tests. 1. "Resource* only" 2. "Resource* and Web*" 3. "Resource* and Web* and `filter-order`". In cases 1 and 3: the filter chain was 12-long, and included a `OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter`, which conferred bearer auth (as desired). but in case 2: the filter chain was 14-long, excluded `OAuth*Filter`, and instead filters such as `User*Password*Filter`.

Comment: If you found any solution for this, please let me know, I am having same issue. here is my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47627226/basic-auth-oauth-implementation-in-spring-boot

Comment: I think is a good answer, however, being a newbie in oauth, I come to this answer and I took _'... it looks like WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter is an order inferior to the ResourceServerConfigurerAdapte'_ as if ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter could be processed before WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter . Just to clarify, WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter seems to have a **higher precedence** over ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter

Comment: As you can define the order using @Order, using the order keyword was on purpose. Still your comment makes sense.

Comment: Since last two days I'm trying to find issue with CORS, Then I figure out by implementing both it let request allow from cross origin.

I think it is related with @nuvio answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45980267/resourceserverconfigureradapter-vs-websecurityconfigureradapter