# Can spring have multiple ConfigurerAdapter?

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2, spring-security-ldap

I need to add OAuth2 security using an ldap authentication.
I have first implemented ldap authenication and add a `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` instance.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@Order(2)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin();
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(final AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.ldapAuthentication()
                .contextSource().url("ldaps://master:636/dc=domain,dc=com")
                .managerDn("cn=readonly,dc=domain,dc=com").managerPassword("123456")
                .and()
                .userSearchFilter("(uid={0})");
    }
}
```

I need to add OAuth2 resource server adapter `ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter`

```
@Configuration
@Import({ DatabaseConfig.class })
@EnableResourceServer
@Order(1)
public class OAuth2ResourceServerConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired DatabaseConfig databaseConfig;

    @Override
    public void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.IF_REQUIRED).and().authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();
    }


    @Bean
    public JwtAccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter() {
        final JwtAccessTokenConverter converter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
        // converter.setSigningKey("123");
        final Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("public.txt");
        String publicKey = null;
        try {
            publicKey = IOUtils.toString(resource.getInputStream());
        } catch (final IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        converter.setVerifierKey(publicKey);
        return converter;
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public DefaultTokenServices tokenServices() {
        final DefaultTokenServices defaultTokenServices = new DefaultTokenServices();
        defaultTokenServices.setTokenStore(tokenStore());
        return defaultTokenServices;
    }


    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new JdbcTokenStore(databaseConfig.dataSource());
    }
```

It seems like WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter and ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter conflicting when both configured.

I am playing with both configure() method but I can only get an access login through ldap using `http://localhost:8080/login` on my Rest API, and couldn't using my angular client using oauth `http://localhost:8081/login`

I have the following error when trying to access the resource:

```
Failed to find refresh token for token eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VyX25hbWUiOiJqb2huIiwic2NvcGUiOlsiZm9vIiwicmVhZCIsIndyaXRlIl0sIm9yZ2FuaXphdGlvbiI6ImpvaG5vRnZiIiwiYXRpIjoiNDcyZTJiNDYtZjgxZS00NGJiLWEwNDMtMGYwZmRjMDMzY2U1IiwiZXhwIjoxNDc2NTQ5NjYzLCJhdXRob3JpdGllcyI6WyJST0xFX1VTRVIiXSwianRpIjoiN2UwNzRkZDktOWI0ZC00MTU0LWJjMzktMDlkY2U4Y2UyZTg2IiwiY2xpZW50X2lkIjoiZm9vQ2xpZW50SWRQYXNzd29yZCJ9.fuarTPL1O00Yg6b3BPibwux1ZtlmrHaPCJkgjsJni_51B3NEHkdB9kqbABK3IkMWMlZdqY8xfR-zMpY9SxFkpRFDfyvosgLcsTZ...
Handling error: InvalidGrantException, Invalid refresh token: eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVC...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same issue. May be my solution is not graceful, but it works for me.

I had tried `OAuth2ResourceServerConfig` which extends `WebSecurityConfig` and implements ResourceServerConfigurer.

Your `OAuth2ResourceServerConfig` must be like this

```
@Configuration
@Import({ DatabaseConfig.class })
@EnableResourceServer
@Order(1)
public class OAuth2ResourceServerConfig extends WebSecurityConfig implements ResourceServerConfigurer {

    @Autowired DatabaseConfig databaseConfig;

    @Override
    public void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.IF_REQUIRED).and().authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();
    }


    @Bean
    public JwtAccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter() {
        final JwtAccessTokenConverter converter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
        // converter.setSigningKey("123");
        final Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("public.txt");
        String publicKey = null;
        try {
            publicKey = IOUtils.toString(resource.getInputStream());
        } catch (final IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        converter.setVerifierKey(publicKey);
        return converter;
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public DefaultTokenServices tokenServices() {
        final DefaultTokenServices defaultTokenServices = new DefaultTokenServices();
        defaultTokenServices.setTokenStore(tokenStore());
        return defaultTokenServices;
    }


    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new JdbcTokenStore(databaseConfig.dataSource());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

According [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35667809/relation-between-websecurityconfigureradapter-and-resourceserverconfigureradapte), I think you can use the previous version by adding this to you config(yml or properties):

```
security:
  oauth2:
    resource:
        filter-order: 3
```

And I tried adding @Order annotation to my source server config as you did, and get the same issue. So, I think @Order annotation doesn't take effect to ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter, but it works fine with WebSecurityConfig. I don't know is it a bug or intended.