# ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter vs WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter

Tags: spring, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I'm currently working on a Oauth2 implementation with Spring Security, and I found many documentations that use `ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter` along with the `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`.

I hope someone can tell me the differences between the two configurations because I really get confused in which `configure(HttpSecurity http)` method to use since both classes offer one.

I've found some similar questions here in stackoverflow but there are not clearly answered.

Answer (score 6):

From reading the JavaDocs I think the only purpose it's to separate the concerns for OAuth2 Resources authentication from the `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapters` which contains all sorts of security filters.

Additionally it seems like you should add `@EnableResourceServer` annotation and provide a @Bean of type `ResourceServerConfigurer` via `ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter`. The annotation will basically create another `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapters` with an hard-coded order of 3.

So to summarise you will have 2 or more `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapters` but one is specific to OAuth2 authentications.

Comment: Thanks ! that makes the picture more clear .. but when I implement the ResourceServer and the WebSecurity it seems that the first one get overwritten by the second, do you have any explanation to that ?

Comment: If you found any solution for this, please let me know, I am having same issue. here is my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47627226/basic-auth-oauth-implementation-in-spring-boot

Comment: @nuvio, can you please look into this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53537133/unable-to-access-resources-with-access-token-spring-boot-oauth2/53546987