# Spring Security basic auth and OAuth together not working

Tags: java, reactjs, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I am trying to create a Spring Boot web application in which I have added functionality to login with username and password or using google OAuth.

But now if I am trying any API it is asking for login using Google. But the user is logged in using email and password.

Now how to handle both scenarios together?

I have added configure method like this:

```java
//for oauth and basic auth

    http
        .antMatcher("/**")
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/","/register", "/login", "/logout").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
        .oauth2Login()
            .and()
        .logout()
            .logoutUrl("/j_spring_security_logout")
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/");

    http
        .csrf().disable();

    http
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/**", "/register", "/login", "/logout").permitAll()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET).hasAnyAuthority("USER", "ADMIN")
            .antMatchers("/product/**").hasAnyAuthority("ADMIN")
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
        .httpBasic();

    http
        .csrf().disable();
```

How to combine basic auth and OAuth together?

Comment: Try following this similar question! It may be of help to you.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50061662/spring-boot-basic-authentication-and-oauth2-in-same-project

Comment: hi @TungPhan I have two types of login for users like basic auth and oAuth. After login one way is to validate the authentic user by a token which I send after login success. Now user is sending me that token in each request but oauth is sending each request to google auth how to handle this.Any suggestion

Comment: @Shubham Add your Spring Security log with `DEBUG` level to your question. If you are redirected to login page then your are not logged in. Maybe your session is removed. Did you send the session token? What URL do you call?

Comment: @AlexeyOsetsky two microservices not required. I think on changing only configure method we can achieve this. I am looking for configure method in which first it should check request-header for basic auth if it is not available then it should redirect to continue with the google page for login.

Comment: @dur no it is redirecting to the correct URL which continues with google. Can you please check the above comment for requirement understanding. Based on that can you suggest the correct configure method.

Comment: @Shubham Show your logs. I already told you, you should not be redirected to any login, if you are already logged in unless you cleared your session. Log will show, if you are using a already logged in session.

Comment: please update your question with the full debug server logs.