# How to support basic authentication and bearer authentication for the REST API project

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, basic-authentication, bearer-token, spring-security-rest

I am new to Spring Security & still learning it so my question can be naive please bear with it.

I have Sprint Boot Rest API project which exposes certain APIs. I have already implemented the bearer token based authentication for all the APIs.
e.g /user , /resource, /appointment

Now for few apis for a particular controller I would like to have the basic authentication implemented. These Apis will be consumed by another service which is not exposed to public.
In order to have the security for the APIs I would like to have basic authentication in place for these apis.
e.g /internal/api1 , internal/api2 .. and so on

I am not able to distinguished between urls in the **ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter** & **WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter**. Also not sure which should be used for adding **basicAuth()** using the antmatchers

Comment: I am not sure how did you implement the SecurityConfiguration, but maybe this question helps you - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47627226/basic-auth-oauth-implementation-in-spring-boot

Answer (score 1):

What you want, by reading your problem, is to have two authentication types (token and httpBasic) for two diffetent endpoints. It can be achieved by creating two different WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter beans. Spring Boot enables this and can be done like bellow:

- @Order(1) - /resource|user|appointment/** protected by bearer token authentication.
- @Order(2) - /internal/** protected by basic auth.

View docs for [Spring Boot](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-Security-2.0#restoring-separation-of-basic-auth-for-actuator-endpoints-but-something-else-for-user-defined-endpoints) and sample code [here](https://github.com/mageddo/java-examples/tree/6a7dd2b426f17a1c5ebab1552f25e8c62d2d9aee/spring-security/basic-and-form-auth-together).

```
   @EnableWebSecurity
   public class SecurityConfig {

    @Configuration
    @Order(1)
    public class ApiSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                .antMatcher("/resource/**")
                .antMatcher("/user/**")
                .antMatcher("/appointment/**")
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and() .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
    .and().addFilterBefore(jwtTokenFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        }
    }

    @Configuration
    @Order(2)
    public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/internal/**")
                .and()
                .httpBasic();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: please, if the answer responds your problem, accept it. Thanks

Comment: I tried the above approach. But this did not work in my case. I have my own class extending  ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter in which I am overriding configure(HttpSecurity http) to by pass the security for some public urls. So if I dont specify the url here for which I want basic auth then it says invalid jwt token but if I specify the url here in configure(HttpSecurity http) then it hits succeessfuly without any authentication