# OAuth2 with Spring Boot REST application - cannot access resource with token

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot, oauth-2.0

I want to use OAuth2 for my  REST spring boot project. Using some examples I have created configuration for OAuth2:

```java
@Configuration
public class OAuth2Configuration {

    private static final String RESOURCE_ID = "restservice";

    @Configuration
    @EnableResourceServer
    protected static class ResourceServerConfiguration extends
          ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) {
            // @formatter:off
            resources
                    .resourceId(RESOURCE_ID);
            // @formatter:on
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            // @formatter:off
            http
                    .anonymous().disable()
                    .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
            // @formatter:on
        }

    }

    @Configuration
    @EnableAuthorizationServer
    protected static class AuthorizationServerConfiguration extends
             AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

        private TokenStore tokenStore = new InMemoryTokenStore();

        @Autowired
        @Qualifier("authenticationManagerBean")
        private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

        @Autowired
        private UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;

        @Override
        public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints)
            throws Exception {
          // @formatter:off
          endpoints
                  .tokenStore(this.tokenStore)
                  .authenticationManager(this.authenticationManager)
                  .userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
          // @formatter:on
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
            // @formatter:off
            clients
                  .inMemory()
                  .withClient("clientapp")
                  .authorizedGrantTypes("password", "refresh_token", "trust")
                  .authorities("USER")
                  .scopes("read", "write")
                  .resourceIds(RESOURCE_ID)
                  .secret("clientsecret")
                  .accessTokenValiditySeconds(1200)
                  .refreshTokenValiditySeconds(3600);
            // @formatter:on
        }

        @Bean
        @Primary
        public DefaultTokenServices tokenServices() {
            DefaultTokenServices tokenServices = new DefaultTokenServices();
            tokenServices.setSupportRefreshToken(true);
            tokenServices.setTokenStore(this.tokenStore);
            return tokenServices;
        }
    }
}
```

This is my SecurityConfiguration class:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@Order(1)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable();
        http
                .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/register").permitAll()
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/free").permitAll()
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/oauth/token").permitAll()
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/secured").hasRole("USER")
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

}
```

I tried to check my application with 2 simple requests:

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/secured", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String checkSecured(){
    return "Authorization is ok";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/api/free", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String checkFree(){
    return "Free from authorization";
}
```

Firstly I checked two requests:

**/api/free** returned code 200 and the string "Free from authorization"

**/api/secured** returned {"timestamp":1487451065106,"status":403,"error":"Forbidden","message":"Access Denied","path":"/api/secured"}

And it seems that they work fine.

Then I got access_token (using credentials from my users database)

**/oauth/token?grant_type=password&username=emaila&password=emailo**

Response:

{"access_token":"3344669f-c66c-4161-9516-d7e2f31a32e8","token_type":"bearer","refresh_token":"c71c17e4-45ba-458c-9d98-574de33d1859","expires_in":1199,"scope":"read write"}

Then I tried to send a request (with the token I got) for resource which requires authentication:

**/api/secured?access_token=3344669f-c66c-4161-9516-d7e2f31a32e8**

Here is response:

{"timestamp":1487451630224,"status":403,"error":"Forbidden","message":"Access Denied","path":"/api/secured"}

I cannot understand why access is denied. I am not sure in configurations and it seems that they are incorrect. Also I still do not clearly understand relationships of methods **configure(HttpSecurity http)** in class which extends **WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter** and in another which extends **ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter**.
Thank you for any help!

Comment: What happens when you send the Token as Header `Authorization: Bearer [TOKEN]`?

Comment: @dav1d I tried but access is still denied

Comment: Your question was helpful, however I got it to work only after removing the "@Order(1)" from your security class. It would have been very beneficial if you provided the full code or a Github link.

Comment: @SamwellTarly Sorry for late reply, here is the link: https://github.com/ahea/SocNetworkSpringApp

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you are using spring boot 1.5.1 or recently updated to it, note that they changed the filter order for spring security oauth2 ([Spring Boot 1.5 Release Notes](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-1.5-Release-Notes#oauth-2-resource-filter)).

According to the release notes, try to add the following property to application.properties/yml, after doing that the resource server filters will be used after your other filters as a fallback - this should cause the authorization to be accepted before falling to the resource server:

```
security.oauth2.resource.filter-order = 3
```

You can find a good answer for your other questions here: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28537181](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28537181/spring-security-oauth2-which-decides-security/28604260#28604260)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I added this property and removed @Order annotation. Now I can get access token and then, using it, finally get /api/secured resource. But I cannot get /api/free without token now. I think it can be fixed by changing configure methods.

Comment: I'm having a similar problem, while I'm requesting a secured resource with the access_token, it seems like this totally ignored and I'm redirected to make login...  
Do you know how can I debug it?

Comment: You might be trying to do an `authorization_code` flow instead of `client_credentials` / `password` flows, in auth code flow you should be redirected to a login page so it makes sense (https://oauth.net/2/grant-types/authorization-code/)

Comment: @Tom can you pls look into this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53537133/unable-to-access-resources-with-access-token-spring-boot-oauth2