# Spring security OAuth2 implementation

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, oauth, oauth-2.0

Using Spring Boot `1.5.2.RELEASE` and Java 8

I'm trying to understand, what goes in `public void configure(HttpSecurity http)` method of `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` and of `ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter`?

With the following code, `configure(HttpSecurity http)` method of  `ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter` is taking precedence over `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`. All the changes I'm doing in `ResourceServerConfiguration` is taking effect, it appears that `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`is ignored completely.

When we use these methods (use case)? And, is override of `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.configure(..)` method even required for grant type `password`

Using `security.oauth2.resource.filter-order = 3`
Without this property I keep getting `403 Access Denied`

> The default order of the OAuth2 resource filter has changed from 3 to SecurityProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER - 1

WebSecurityConfiguration

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable()
    .authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/unsecured").permitAll()
    .antMatchers("/users").hasRole("USER")
    .antMatchers("/api/secured").hasRole("ADMIN")
    .antMatchers("/api/admin").authenticated()
    .antMatchers("/greeting").authenticated();
  }
}
```

Resource Server

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
protected static class ResourceServerConfiguration extends
        ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().permitAll();          
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have the answer here, please check out the solution given
[Spring Security OAuth2, which decides security?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28537181/spring-security-oauth2-which-decides-security)