# CORS not working in a project where both ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter and WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter is present

Tags: spring, rest, spring-security, spring-oauth2

I came across this project in order to fix a issue which the server is responding with **401** unautorized to a **OPTIONS** request.

I looked in the project and ( It is a Spring 5 project bundled as a ear not a boot ) found that there is a CORS filter. Then I looked into security configs and found that there is two.

```
//@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private CustomUserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;

    @Bean
    public CustomDaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvier() {
        CustomDaoAuthenticationProvider customProvider = new CustomDaoAuthenticationProvider();
        customProvider.setUserDetailsService(customUserDetailsService);
        customProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return customProvider;
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvier());

    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .cors()
                .and()
                .csrf().disable()
                .anonymous().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/**").permitAll();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(10);
    }

}
```

The second one is

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
@EnableWebSecurity
public class OAuth2ResourceServerConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.anonymous().disable().sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()

                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/somepath/**").access("#oauth2.hasScope('some_scope') "
                + "and hasAnyRole('role_1','r')")
                ....
                .anyRequest().authenticated();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(final ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer config) {
        config.tokenServices(tokenServices());
    }

    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new JwtTokenStore(accessTokenConverter());
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtAccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter() {
        final JwtAccessTokenConverter converter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();

        ClassPathResource resource = new ClassPathResource("id_rsa.pub");
        String publicKey = null;
        try {
            publicKey = new String(FileCopyUtils.copyToByteArray(resource.getInputStream()));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        converter.setVerifierKey(publicKey);
        return converter;
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public DefaultTokenServices tokenServices() {
        final DefaultTokenServices defaultTokenServices = new DefaultTokenServices();
        defaultTokenServices.setTokenStore(tokenStore());
        return defaultTokenServices;
    }

}
```

After reading questions related to this what I figured it that OAuth2ResourceServerConfig gets precedence over WebSecurityConfig ( question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28537181/spring-security-oauth2-which-decides-security/28604260#28604260) ).

So in the current set is it checking for both token and the password?
If I increase the precedence of WebSecurityConfig will it solve the issue. If I have misunderstood anything here please fix it for me.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue too!

So what I did, I just exchange the `OPTIONS` request implicitly. Because Optional Request is just from browser to server to check whether `Service` is working or not.

If you notice, when we test endpoint from `POSTMAN` then this issue not apears.

So what I did

```
@Component
public class SecretKeyFilter implements WebFilter {

    @Override
    public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, WebFilterChain chain) {
        ServerHttpRequest request = exchange.getRequest();
        HttpHeaders headers = request.getHeaders();

        if(!request.getMethod().name().equals("OPTIONS"))
        {
            
          /**
           * Do the authentication and valication of your request here.
           *
          **/
        }

        return chain.filter(exchange);
    }
}
```

Comment: Does it work like this? Because other than skipping the security check server need to set certain response headers like allowed origins etc

Comment: I am saying that! Just skip the `OPTIONS` request, because `OPTIONS` request will not take your Auth params with it, like some `headers` which contains `Auth token`  or any other param.

So just Skip the `OPTIONS` request and then Capture the other one and then apply the Security Aspects